# React app website page only loads upon refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router, react-router-dom

Everything works fine when in my website, except everytime for the page to render correctly I have to refresh my page. I have tried the numerous solutions out there, except nothing works.

This is the code for the app component.

```js
function App() {
return (
 <BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/skills" component={Skills} />
      <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
      <Route path="/work" component={Work} />
      <Route path="/blogs" component={Blogs} />
      <Route path="/blogs/blog-details"component={BlogDetails}/>
       <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
   </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Please someone help so that when I go to each of the pages, it just works!!

Comment: Have you tried creating the App component as a class component and the routing inside a render method?

Comment: Similar to the solution below?

Comment: Yes, you need to use class App extends React.Component or you need to import Component from react library like "import React, { Component } from 'react';"

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import Home from './home'; //Full path of your page
import About from './about'; //Full path of your page
import Skills from './skills'; //Full path of your page
import Projects from './projects'; //Full path of your page
import Work from './work'; //Full path of your page
import Blogs from './blogs'; //Full path of your page
import BlogDetails from './blogs/blog-details'; //Full path of your page
import Contact from './contact'; //Full path of your page

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/skills" component={Skills} />
            <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
            <Route path="/work" component={Work} />
            <Route path="/blogs" component={Blogs} />
            <Route path="/blog-details"component={BlogDetails}/>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It says Component is not defined :((

Comment: You need to define each and every component and import with proper path.

Comment: I've done that but the error is coming on the line "App extends Component"

Comment: @A.G please check if you added "import React, { Component } from 'react';" on top of your imports.

Comment: Yep added and seems to be better than before but still occasionally just gives me a black screen and then I have to reload the page for it to work.

Comment: Can you open your console and see if there is any warnings or error message?

Comment: Nope no warning messages